# Using Vue in Laravel Spark - "method not defined on the instance" using vue2-touch-events - what could I do differently?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-spark

I am trying to build a very simple, tinder-like swiping application using Laravel Spark and vue2-touch-events. I assume I am doing something extraordinarily dumb, so I appreciate your insight.

I get this warning in my Vue inspector:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "swipeHandler" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Here is my simple version of all of the relevant code. I changed the v-touch:swipe to just longtap for testing.

/resources/js/app.js:

```
require('spark-bootstrap');

require('./components/bootstrap');

require('vue2-touch-events');

Vue.component('swipeHandler', './components/swipehandler.vue');

var app = new Vue({
    mixins: [require('spark')],
    components: {
        vue2touchevents,
        swipeHandler
    },
});
```

swipe.blade.php:

```
@extends('spark::layouts.app')

@section('content')
<home :user="user" inline-template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center flex-column-reverse flex-md-row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card text-center">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div><i v-touch:longtap="swipeHandler">Swipe Here</i></div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</home>
@endsection
```

/resources/js/components/swipehandler.vue:

```
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        swipeHandler () {
            alert("yay!");
            console.log("yay!");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Best guess is that you may want to try and add a template to your /resources/js/components/swipehandler.vue component:

```
<template>
    <div>Yay</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        swipeHandler () {
            alert("yay!");
            console.log("yay!");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm not too familiar with how `vue2-touch-events` works, so I would need to understand that a bit more to give you a better answer.

Best of luck.

Comment: I find that this is true for any library I use. And I fail to get working code even if I don't have a swipeHandler.vue. The documentation says all I have to do is:


`import Vue from 'vue'`
`import Vue2TouchEvents from 'vue2-touch-events'`
 
`Vue.use(Vue2TouchEvents)`

In your .vue file:

`<!-- bind a tap event -->`
`<span v-touch:tap="touchHandler">Tap Me</span>`


(https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-touch-events)

I feel like I am interacting with libraries in the wrong way bc I get the same problem using other libraries (e.g. https://vue2-interact.netlify.app/)